# Routine disconnects if not on VPN. Can I bypass ISP?

Tags: vpn, internet, isp

I am living in the Philippines and I am playing world of Warcraft on a west coast server in the USA. I get around 180ms ping between like midnight and 759am. At 8am I get disconnected and then when I log back in it is incredibly laggy with 12000 ping. This happens every day at the same time.

I subscribed to PIA which allows me to use a VPN to connect and I get a steady 259ms ping all day and night. What is causing this? I assume the ISP is changing something about how they route traffic.

Is there a way around this? The customer service is awful. I can't even call support. They assigned me one contact and he never answers my calls or responds to texts. I just bought an Asus rt-ac68u router a few minutes ago and subscribed to dyndns to see if that might help. Is there a way to bypass my ISPs traffic routing or replace the old technicolor modem they provided to me. I just want a stable connection, spare no expense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly with your ISP, and you have already found the workaround - use a VPN to modify your traffic profile in a way that it gets priority.   If you want a lower ping, the trick might be to find a VPN provider more directly in the path between yourself and the server.  (If your VPN is not provided out of the West Coast, maybe shift to a server that is ?)

The alternative solution would be to change ISP's.

Whats most likely happening is that your ISP is breaking the bandwidth up into pools, and, it appears, they don't particularly cater to gamers. (Its also possible its a routing bottleneck the VPN works around)

Its possible, but unlikely that your ISP is "changing the way it routes traffic".  Its more likely that its a combination of the way your connection is delivered  [ are you using DSL?  If so, many variants renegotiate periodically, and this may be happening at 8am for you ], and the usage profile - Your low latency times coincide with off-peak times.

DynDNS won't help your performance issues, and neither will the new router (unless you want to run the VPN from that - and its a nice piece of kit worth having anyway)

Comment: This is a 50mbps cable connection. The only alternative is an 8mbps dsl from another provider but I've had bad experiences with them, although I haven't seriously been gaming for about 7 years. Is there any path I should take, for example, I could save tracert logs for a period of time and try to show how the latency increases at certain points in the day? This is frustrating because I have no choices.

Comment: The problem appears to be one of how to get the level of support you need from your ISP.  Doing regular mtrs (traceroute + ping) to provide them could help the technicians in your ISP - if you can get them to look at it.  (At a serious business/ISP level, I have written scripts to graph pings + latency and this has provided compelling evidence in getting problems fixed on the ISP end - Look at http://serverfault.com/questions/342349/graphical-ping-utility-with-logging for software recommendations which might do something similar - This will only help if you can make your ISP care though.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll attempt. Nothing to lose and no other options